# Github Services / Ruby Gem "eventmachine" Mac installation woes

Tags: ruby, github, rubygems, eventmachine, github-services

I don't think it particularly matters, but my branch of the Github Services repo is https://github.com/franklovecchio/github-services

When I try to run "sudo ruby github-services.rb" to test my hook, it trys to install eventmachine, which gives the error below (I can install other gems!).  I've done `gem update` as well, but still get the same error. The `bundler` gem is installed as well. Anybody seen this?

```
sudo ruby github-services.rb 
Password:
WARN The gem environment is out-of-date or has yet to be bootstrapped.
     Runnning script/bootstrap to remedy this situation...
Using rake (0.8.7) 
Using activesupport (3.0.10) 
Using builder (2.1.2) 
Using i18n (0.5.0) 
Using activemodel (3.0.10) 
Using activeresource (3.0.10) 
Using addressable (2.2.6) 
Installing eventmachine (0.12.10) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... no
checking for __NR_inotify_init in sys/syscall.h... no
checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_check_ints()... yes
checking for rb_time_new()... yes
checking for sys/event.h... yes
checking for sys/queue.h... yes
creating Makefile

make
/usr/bin/g++-4.2 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.7.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DBUILD_FOR_RUBY -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_BLOCKING_REGION -DHAVE_TBR -DHAVE_WRITEV -DHAVE_WRITEV -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_CHECK_INTS -DHAVE_RB_TIME_NEW -DOS_UNIX -DHAVE_SYS_EVENT_H -DHAVE_SYS_QUEUE_H -DHAVE_KQUEUE -DWITH_SSL -DHAVE_MAKE_PAIR -I/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.1/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -fno-common  -w -pipe -O3 -fno-common -I/opt/local/include     -w -pipe -O3 -o binder.o -c binder.cpp
/usr/bin/g++-4.2 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.7.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DBUILD_FOR_RUBY -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_BLOCKING_REGION -DHAVE_TBR -DHAVE_WRITEV -DHAVE_WRITEV -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_CHECK_INTS -DHAVE_RB_TIME_NEW -DOS_UNIX -DHAVE_SYS_EVENT_H -DHAVE_SYS_QUEUE_H -DHAVE_KQUEUE -DWITH_SSL -DHAVE_MAKE_PAIR -I/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.1/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -fno-common  -w -pipe -O3 -fno-common -I/opt/local/include     -w -pipe -O3 -o cmain.o -c cmain.cpp
/usr/bin/g++-4.2 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.7.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DBUILD_FOR_RUBY -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_BLOCKING_REGION -DHAVE_TBR -DHAVE_WRITEV -DHAVE_WRITEV -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_CHECK_INTS -DHAVE_RB_TIME_NEW -DOS_UNIX -DHAVE_SYS_EVENT_H -DHAVE_SYS_QUEUE_H -DHAVE_KQUEUE -DWITH_SSL -DHAVE_MAKE_PAIR -I/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.1/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -fno-common  -w -pipe -O3 -fno-common -I/opt/local/include     -w -pipe -O3 -o cplusplus.o -c cplusplus.cpp
/usr/bin/g++-4.2 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.7.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DBUILD_FOR_RUBY -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_BLOCKING_REGION -DHAVE_TBR -DHAVE_WRITEV -DHAVE_WRITEV -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_CHECK_INTS -DHAVE_RB_TIME_NEW -DOS_UNIX -DHAVE_SYS_EVENT_H -DHAVE_SYS_QUEUE_H -DHAVE_KQUEUE -DWITH_SSL -DHAVE_MAKE_PAIR -I/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.1/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -fno-common  -w -pipe -O3 -fno-common -I/opt/local/include     -w -pipe -O3 -o ed.o -c ed.cpp
/usr/bin/g++-4.2 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.7.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DBUILD_FOR_RUBY -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_BLOCKING_REGION -DHAVE_TBR -DHAVE_WRITEV -DHAVE_WRITEV -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_CHECK_INTS -DHAVE_RB_TIME_NEW -DOS_UNIX -DHAVE_SYS_EVENT_H -DHAVE_SYS_QUEUE_H -DHAVE_KQUEUE -DWITH_SSL -DHAVE_MAKE_PAIR -I/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.1/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -fno-common  -w -pipe -O3 -fno-common -I/opt/local/include     -w -pipe -O3 -o em.o -c em.cpp
/usr/bin/g++-4.2 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.7.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DBUILD_FOR_RUBY -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_BLOCKING_REGION -DHAVE_TBR -DHAVE_WRITEV -DHAVE_WRITEV -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_CHECK_INTS -DHAVE_RB_TIME_NEW -DOS_UNIX -DHAVE_SYS_EVENT_H -DHAVE_SYS_QUEUE_H -DHAVE_KQUEUE -DWITH_SSL -DHAVE_MAKE_PAIR -I/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.1/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -fno-common  -w -pipe -O3 -fno-common -I/opt/local/include     -w -pipe -O3 -o emwin.o -c emwin.cpp
/usr/bin/g++-4.2 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.7.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DBUILD_FOR_RUBY -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_BLOCKING_REGION -DHAVE_TBR -DHAVE_WRITEV -DHAVE_WRITEV -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_CHECK_INTS -DHAVE_RB_TIME_NEW -DOS_UNIX -DHAVE_SYS_EVENT_H -DHAVE_SYS_QUEUE_H -DHAVE_KQUEUE -DWITH_SSL -DHAVE_MAKE_PAIR -I/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.1/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -fno-common  -w -pipe -O3 -fno-common -I/opt/local/include     -w -pipe -O3 -o epoll.o -c epoll.cpp
/usr/bin/g++-4.2 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.7.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DBUILD_FOR_RUBY -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_BLOCKING_REGION -DHAVE_TBR -DHAVE_WRITEV -DHAVE_WRITEV -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_CHECK_INTS -DHAVE_RB_TIME_NEW -DOS_UNIX -DHAVE_SYS_EVENT_H -DHAVE_SYS_QUEUE_H -DHAVE_KQUEUE -DWITH_SSL -DHAVE_MAKE_PAIR -I/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.1/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -fno-common  -w -pipe -O3 -fno-common -I/opt/local/include     -w -pipe -O3 -o files.o -c files.cpp
/usr/bin/g++-4.2 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.7.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DBUILD_FOR_RUBY -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_BLOCKING_REGION -DHAVE_TBR -DHAVE_WRITEV -DHAVE_WRITEV -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_CHECK_INTS -DHAVE_RB_TIME_NEW -DOS_UNIX -DHAVE_SYS_EVENT_H -DHAVE_SYS_QUEUE_H -DHAVE_KQUEUE -DWITH_SSL -DHAVE_MAKE_PAIR -I/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.1/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -fno-common  -w -pipe -O3 -fno-common -I/opt/local/include     -w -pipe -O3 -o kb.o -c kb.cpp
/usr/bin/g++-4.2 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.7.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DBUILD_FOR_RUBY -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_BLOCKING_REGION -DHAVE_TBR -DHAVE_WRITEV -DHAVE_WRITEV -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_CHECK_INTS -DHAVE_RB_TIME_NEW -DOS_UNIX -DHAVE_SYS_EVENT_H -DHAVE_SYS_QUEUE_H -DHAVE_KQUEUE -DWITH_SSL -DHAVE_MAKE_PAIR -I/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.1/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -fno-common  -w -pipe -O3 -fno-common -I/opt/local/include     -w -pipe -O3 -o page.o -c page.cpp
/usr/bin/g++-4.2 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.7.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DBUILD_FOR_RUBY -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_BLOCKING_REGION -DHAVE_TBR -DHAVE_WRITEV -DHAVE_WRITEV -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_CHECK_INTS -DHAVE_RB_TIME_NEW -DOS_UNIX -DHAVE_SYS_EVENT_H -DHAVE_SYS_QUEUE_H -DHAVE_KQUEUE -DWITH_SSL -DHAVE_MAKE_PAIR -I/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.1/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -fno-common  -w -pipe -O3 -fno-common -I/opt/local/include     -w -pipe -O3 -o pipe.o -c pipe.cpp
/usr/bin/g++-4.2 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.7.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DBUILD_FOR_RUBY -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_BLOCKING_REGION -DHAVE_TBR -DHAVE_WRITEV -DHAVE_WRITEV -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_CHECK_INTS -DHAVE_RB_TIME_NEW -DOS_UNIX -DHAVE_SYS_EVENT_H -DHAVE_SYS_QUEUE_H -DHAVE_KQUEUE -DWITH_SSL -DHAVE_MAKE_PAIR -I/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.1/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -fno-common  -w -pipe -O3 -fno-common -I/opt/local/include     -w -pipe -O3 -o rubymain.o -c rubymain.cpp
/usr/bin/g++-4.2 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.7.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DBUILD_FOR_RUBY -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_BLOCKING_REGION -DHAVE_TBR -DHAVE_WRITEV -DHAVE_WRITEV -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_CHECK_INTS -DHAVE_RB_TIME_NEW -DOS_UNIX -DHAVE_SYS_EVENT_H -DHAVE_SYS_QUEUE_H -DHAVE_KQUEUE -DWITH_SSL -DHAVE_MAKE_PAIR -I/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.1/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -fno-common  -w -pipe -O3 -fno-common -I/opt/local/include     -w -pipe -O3 -o sigs.o -c sigs.cpp
/usr/bin/g++-4.2 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.7.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DBUILD_FOR_RUBY -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_BLOCKING_REGION -DHAVE_TBR -DHAVE_WRITEV -DHAVE_WRITEV -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_CHECK_INTS -DHAVE_RB_TIME_NEW -DOS_UNIX -DHAVE_SYS_EVENT_H -DHAVE_SYS_QUEUE_H -DHAVE_KQUEUE -DWITH_SSL -DHAVE_MAKE_PAIR -I/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.1/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -fno-common  -w -pipe -O3 -fno-common -I/opt/local/include     -w -pipe -O3 -o ssl.o -c ssl.cpp
/usr/bin/g++-4.2 -dynamic -bundle -o rubyeventmachine.bundle binder.o cmain.o cplusplus.o ed.o em.o emwin.o epoll.o files.o kb.o page.o pipe.o rubymain.o sigs.o ssl.o -L. -L/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/lib -L. -L/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.1/lib -L/opt/local/lib -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress -Wl,-flat_namespace  -lruby.1.9.1  -lssl -lcrypto -lz   -lpthread -ldl -lobjc 
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/local/lib/libz.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
ld: in /opt/local/lib/libz.1.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64) for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [rubyeventmachine.bundle] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/franklovecchio/Desktop/development/github_services/vendor/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/franklovecchio/Desktop/development/github_services/vendor/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/ext/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing eventmachine (0.12.10), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install eventmachine -v '0.12.10'` succeeds before bundling.
bundle executable not found.  Ensure bundler is installed (`gem install bundler`) and that the gem bin path is in your PATH
WARN The gem environment is STILL out-of-date.
     Please contact your network administrator.
/Users/franklovecchio/Desktop/development/github_services/config/load.rb:26:in `<top (required)>': gem environment not configued (RuntimeError)
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from github-services.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

Looking at the `gem environment`:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 180) [x86_64-darwin10.7.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-10
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - /Users/franklovecchio/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :sources => ["http://rubygems.org/", "http://gems.github.com"]
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
     - http://gems.github.com
```

Comment: the errors seems to be coming from /opt/local/lib/libz.1.dylib. I suspect that there's a previous installation of macports compiled for another architecture than x86_64 on your computer

Answer (score 0):

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/local/lib/libz.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
```

This is the main error. do check Zlib port, is it installed for x86_64? you can do that using

```
port -v installed zlib
```

if zlib is NOT installed, do install it or if its already installed. just update it.

Further, if this doesn't help. Have a look at [Fixing ld: warning: in /usr/local/lib/libz.dylib, file is not of required architecture](http://www.refresherate.com/2010/01/08/fixing-ld-warning-in-usrlocalliblibz-dylib-file-is-not-of-required-architecture/)